# Why was this highly upvoted answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/69054/10051) got a score of **134** (10k users can see the deleted answer), only handful of answers reached that in travel.SE, yet it was deleted by a mod. Some might think of the answer as a sarcastic answer, but I do not think so, and many others share the same opinion with me. In my opinion, it was a legitimate answer to a poor question.

Why did the mod take that decision? the problem here is we (the community) can not vote to undelete it, since it was deleted by a mod. This is unfair in my opinion. I might be wrong, hence I hope that mods can explain this.

Last thing, he is a new user, what happened to Rule #1 and be nice specially to new users ;) ?

Comment: Let's restore the answer.  There is currently an override on it which prevents a community decision.

Comment: The combined effect of having the answer deleted and the question being completely locked (now it's merely protected, which is less restrictive) felt fairly problematic. Not only was the top answer as voted by the community summarily deleted, nobody could answer or comment, not even Heidel Ber Gensis to state that some answers are wrong based on his experience. While I understand that the comments section was getting long, that situation is usually managed by deleting problematic comments or moving the discussion to chat instead of locking the whole question.

Answer (score 9):

It's a correct and valid answer -- that's for sure. Just not very helpful. The problem I have with such non-answering answers is that they can be applied to many [air-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-travel) questions.

> Problems with toddlers? Get a private jet.
>
> Too little luggage on the flight? Get a private jet.
>
> Inconvenient transfers? Get a private jet.

.. and many more.

You probably see where I'm going with this. Travel-SE is supposed to be helpful towards its users. Put yourself in OP's shoes and see how you will react to such an answer if you are a first-time user. Would you come back and answer another question that you might have? Unlikely, if you are met with such "help" the first time around.

Allowing such answers implicitly says they are okay, which may (or may not -- I'm not willing to test this theory) lead to many more in the future, citing as precedent this particular answer.

In case it's not obvious, it was me who deleted the post.

**Edit:** It seems many people disagree with my decision, and it is your prerogative as a community to question moderators' actions. For those of you who disagree, I suggest flagging the question to ask for the post be undeleted, and explaining your reasoning. I will not take any action with such flags, and if another moderator disagrees with my decision, I'm sure they will undelete the post.

**Edit 2:** After some discussion with the post author, they agreed to edit and expand it so it doesn't sound so sarcastic (which I'm sure wasn't the intention in the first place). The answer is now undeleted.

Comment: As a pro in the airlines business, specifically in airplane cabin business, all the other answers are WRONG. the deleted answer is the ONLY correct answer. Just saying. Please reconsider undeleting the answer. thank you.

Comment: Would you reconsider if the answer was made longer (agreed on before opening if needed) and given arguments or some such?

Comment: Sometimes an answer should be retained. I travel that way almost all the time and suggest that this aspect where TSE intervenes against private aircraft is forfeiting a group of potential users who might have very interesting tips-and-techniques. I don't see any conditions requiring TSE to cater exclusively to the shoe-string budget crowd either.

Comment: To me, the private jet answer is the only real answer to the actual question the OP asked, which was how to ensure "this experience will never, ever repeat itself" (I suppose the pay someone else to switch seats with you answer can work, but that has practicality issues of its own). The implied question in there, which most other people answered, is more like "what are some tips and tricks for minimizing the annoyance of loud kids on planes?" It's great to address both, but the one answer that literally answers the question should not have been deleted.

Comment: "Problems with toddlers?" This is typically mitigated by noise suppression, noise cancellation or by providing an alternative audio source such as music

"Too little luggage on the flight?." Additional luggage entitlement comes with paying for business class or first, or comes with higher status in the airline programme, and almost always can be just purchased.

"Inconvenient transfers?" There are many sites that can be used to find direct flights are convenient transfers. For example, matrix.itasoftware.com takes an option /maxconnect nnn to restrict the connection time between flights.

Comment: How to *avoid* toddlers/drunks/snorers etc is not solvable except by taking alternative private transport such as going on a cruise, driving or taking private jet. Perhaps it would be best to advise people to ask the right question rather than not accepting the correct answer to their question.

Comment: Going on a cruise is generally not a good way to avoid drunks. Whether it helps you avoid toddlers will depend on the cruise line and itinerary.

Comment: Even though I disagree with this answer, thanks for giving it.

Comment: On a cruise there are plenty of places to go to remove yourself from an uncomfortable situation, e.g. back to your own cabin. Not something you can typically do on a flight though.

Comment: Thanks to Jetshare companies selling empty seats or  legs and the growth in private jet charters, for any question where "Fly first class" is an option, "Fly a private jet" is also an option -- A full price LAX->NYC first class seat can cost $4000+ (though deals can be had for much lower), an 8 passenger jet can be chartered for the same trip for $5000 per seat.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is still an answer to the question, so I'll put it here rather than a comment.

Irrespective of whether people thought I was being sarcastic or not, there was and still is both up and down voting happening on my modified answer. I honestly think my edited answer shows no sign of sarcasm but is still being downvoted.

So, why was my answer deleted? I think that the controversial question  provoked a controversial answer. I did consider all possible responses to avoiding children and researched cruises from London to San Francisco too, but realised that that wasn't an answer since the question only asked about flying.

Perhaps what I should have done was flagged the question and got a moderator to either edit it or encourage the questioner to rephrase it in a non-controversial way, such that it wouldn't provoke controversial answers.

I apologise if anyone thought I was disrespecting travel SE.